# Extracting URL data from moz_places table within Places.Sqlite in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a program to copy out the places.sqlite file to USB storage, however I am needing to access this file to extract all URLs from the moz_places table. What would be the best method to achieve this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just do this:

```
SQLiteConnection sqlite_connectionMoz = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path_to_db + ";Version=3;");
sqlite_Moz = sqlite_connectionMoz.CreateCommand();
                            sqlite_connectionMoz.Open();
sqlite_Moz.CommandText = "SELECT moz_places.url FROM moz_places";`
```